# I want to update login with username or email in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have updated laravel default ***make:Auth*** to Login with both username and email.
I just have override username function in

***loginController.php*** to:

```
public function username()
    {
        $loginType = request()->input('username');
        $this->username = filter_var($loginType , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
        request()->merge([$this->username => $loginType]);
        $this->property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
    }
```

but got an error:

```
Method [property_exists] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController].
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `$this->property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';`? Do you want to override a variable then?

Comment: @Paul yes sir !

Comment: Besides the wrong code itself (see Pavels answer), you are not doing anything there. This looks like a condition to me, but you are not overriding anything for example.

Comment: @Paul Link plz ?

Answer (score 0):

`property_exists` is a php function, not a method from some class. So, to improve this error, just rewrite your code:

```
public function username()
{
    $loginType = request()->input('username');
    $this->username = filter_var($loginType , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    request()->merge([$this->username => $loginType]);
    property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> property_exists — Checks if the object or class has a property
>
> bool property_exists ( mixed $class , string $property )

```
public function username()
{
    $loginType = request()->input('username');
    $this->username = filter_var($loginType , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    request()->merge([$this->username => $loginType]);
    property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `username()` method in the LoginController refers to the username **field name** sent by the request. In your case I would imagine the field name is the same but what changes is whether you use that field to find an email or username. In that case you should be able to "trick" the user provider to do this by overriding the `credentials` method in your LoginController (and don't override the `username` function):

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $v = \Validator::make($request->only($this->username()), [
         $this->username() => "email"
    ]);
    if ($v->passes()) {
        return [
           "email" => $request->input($this->username()),
           "password" => $request->input("password") 
       ]; 
    } else {
       return [
           "username" => $request->input($this->username()),
           "password" => $request->input("password") 
       ]; 
    }
}
```

This will be passed to the user provider which will select the user either by the `email` column or by the `username` column depending on what is passed.

Comment: not sure why this is being downvoted. is it not working?